# Issue with seaborn twinx - Only one graph is displaying

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, plotly, seaborn

I want to plot 2 subplot. The First subplot is using only one y-axis and is working as expected, in second subplot i want to create dual y -axis and plot line and bar plot. But seems like only barplot is rendering, Can someplease please highlight where i am going wrong ?

```
f,axes =plt.subplots(1,2)
sns.set_theme(style='whitegrid',palette="pastel")
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(20.7,3.27)})
plt.figure(figsize=(20.7,3.27))
 
        # Single Y-Axis in left side plot
sns.lineplot(x='date', y="visit", data=df[(df['Website'] == url)], ci= None,ax=axes[0]).set_title(url)
sns.lineplot(x='date', y="visit_industry", data=df[(df['Website'] == url)], ci= None,ax=axes[0]).set_title(url)

 
    ## Dual Y- Axis in right hand side plot.
ax2 = axes[1].twinx()
sns.lineplot(x='date', y="yoy_change", data=df[(df['Website'] == url)],color='blue',ax=ax2)
sns.barplot(x='date', y="yoy_change_industry", data=df[(df['Website'] == url)],color='black',ax=ax2)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: You should remove `plt.figure(...)` as it creates a new empty figure. You can adjust the figsize as a parameter in `plt.subplots(..., figsize=...)`.

Comment: @JohanC No Change, same issue

Comment: https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions-(FAQs)#why-cant-i-draw-a-line-over-a-barboxstripviolin-plot